# Can't focus back to maps after clicking an item on recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, maps

Im trying to display items over maps fragment using recycler view. Recycler view is defined inside the map fragment. When I click an item from the recycler view I reset adapter data by calling listname.clear() and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().
The recycler view clears but I can't move my map again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Nearby" >

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapConstraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/selectListBtn"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
        android:text="Select Your List"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/selectListRecycler"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/selectListRecycler"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="59dp"
        map:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        map:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/selectListBtn" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Somehow I managed to regain the focus on map by setting visibility of recyclerview to View.GONE , but the button comes to middle of the fragment and alignment goes wrong.

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.selectListRecycler);
                ArrayList<TList> tempList = tLists;
                parent = (ViewGroup) recyclerView.getParent();
                //RecyclerView tempView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.selectListRecycler);
                adapter = new TListRecyclerAdapter(tempList);

                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getContext(),
                        recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
                        selectedList = tLists.get(position);
                        tempList.clear();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                        //Toast.makeText(Nearby.this, "Long press on position :"+position,
                        //        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        String x="";
                    }
                }));
```

[Before clicking select list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCde8.jpg)

[After clicking select list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfxln.jpg)

[After setting recyclerview visibility to GONE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXwc3.jpg)

Comment: Try to rework your layout, because your button constrained to recycler view and vice versa. Create some barrier to constraint your views to it, or something like it.

Comment: @H.Taras Will try it .Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option - 1:** Simply remove `map:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/selectListRecycler"` from `Button`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/selectListBtn"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
    android:text="Select Your List"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    map:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    map:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**Option - 2:** 
Instead of `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` use `LinearLayout` with orientation vertical.

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Comment: Thanks. Removing map:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/selectListRecycler" worked